# windvd aacs keys update dosn't work

Tags: blu-ray

A relative has a viao htpc, which has blue ray. The player I believe is a viao branded version of windvd with blue ray support.

Every time it loads it asks if it should update the aacs keys as they are out of date. If you select yes nothing happens. The package just sits there forever saying that you shouldn't turn it off.

I have tried to go to the products website (which is now corel) registering and downloading the keys, but the key download page does nothing.

Has anyone had a similar problem, or are there any suggestions to get around it?

Comment: Bug your congressperson to get the anti-circumvention provisions of the DMCA repealed.

Comment: Have you tried calling Corel and bugging them about this? The best solution should be to fix the website.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried this already - 
Run the BD playback software as admin: right click on the icon and select run as adminstrator.
It'll give you the same AACS msg but will actually go ahead and download the update for you.

Or try this - after the aacs warning cancel the msg out and hit the play button. See if it plays normally.